# anti-aliasing issues

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, anti-aliasing

This seems to happen most of the time, but more visible when you are importing as smart objects in Photoshop and resizing down. In the attached image you can see where the aliasing is getting really bad in the top right where I blew up what I see when I zoom in. Is there a way to avoid this kind of aliasing?

You can see when its large, the bad aliasing is obfuscated because of the size, but its very noticeable as you get smaller.

also, I have narrowed it down to the use of inner glow, it seems this is what causes it.

[image]

Comment: Posible duplicates: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=smart+object+anti-alias

Comment: not duplicate, already looked. This is specifically to do with use of inner glow.

Comment: Do you have the same problem in an exported jg or png, or is it just 'inside' Photoshop?

Comment: It is actually not "noticable" at all at the small size, beyond the normal-run-of-the-mill aliasing which cannot be eliminated. Zooming in is a red herring. Raster images are meant to be seen at a single size. They are fixed-resolution images.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm concerned, when you use any effects like glow, some kind of rasterisation is applied to the object.

This is most noticeable on some sizes than others when scaling,  and is notable  in Photoshop, afx and flash.

I prefer paths and shapes over smart objects because of this issue. Also It seems all smart object are rasterized, in some way.